# How to configure multiple scopes for DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

We have DHCP setup at the office on one of our Windows Server 2008 boxes. Everyone that has a wired connection goes through our router at `10.10.10.1` and is assigned an address from our DHCP server at `10.10.10.20`. The DHCP scope is setup to assign IPs for `10.10.10.50-200`.

Then, we added a wireless network using the same scope and we ran out of IPs. The wireless router has an IP of `10.10.20.1` and has DHCP running on it that assigns clients an address of `10.10.20.50-200`. This is fine, except that I want to manage the DHCP on the Windows 2008 Server at `10.10.10.20`. If I turn off the DHCP on the wireless router how do I guarantee that all wireless devices will get assigned an IP from the proper scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a separate subnet for wireless on your router/L3 switch
   and set up the necessary routes to/from it.
2. Don't use the wireless router as a router, use in L2 bridged mode. This will make it into an AP. You don't want to route with that device, let your core L3 switch/router do the routing.
3. Put a DHCP forwarder entry (IP Helper in Cisco speak) that
   points at your DHCP server on that router/L3 switch.
4. Create the scope for the 10.10.20.0/24 subnet on the DHCP
   server.

If you have a flat L2 network structure internally, you won't be able to do this. You'll have to create a separate subnet for wireless. It's pretty common, though, so don't think it's unusual to do.

---

In the event that you have all SOHO gear in your office and don't have a *real* capable router that can handle vlans/multiple subnets/ip helpers/etc, just make your 10.10.10.0/24 into a /23 or /22 and broaden your scope. It would all be on the same broadcast domain, which is less than idea, but perfectly doable at that size. You don't *really* need to start separating traffic until you have a packed /21, in my experience.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a separate subnet". Does that give it a different subnet mask?

Comment: I think you might need to [read this excellent Q&A about subnetting](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work). 10.10.10.0/24 (your current wired network) is a subnet. Your wireless scope of 10.10.20.0/24 is also a subnet. For traffic on different subnets to reach their destination, there have to be **routes** in place. This is what a router (or L3 switch - a specialized router for internal core networks) does. You need to define these subnets on your core routing device as a first step to getting what you want.